# Node, express, process ".." symbol in url

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking to get node (using express for routing) to resolve all occurrences of the `../` symbol in urls before performing any routing on the url.

For example if apache is queried at the url `/a/b/../c/d/e/../../f`, it will first resolve all the `../` symbols and will finally serve any content located at `/a/c/f`.

With node+express, however, `/a/b/../c/d/e/../../f` is taken literally and will not match routing for `/a/c/f`. My problem is that the following code will not respond to a request like `/a/b/../c/d/e/../../f`:

```
app.get('/a/c/f', function(req, res) {
   return res.status(200).json({ msg: 'it worked!' }); 
});
```

How can I get node+express to resolve `../` symbols in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the path module to join the URL segments:

```
const path = require("path");

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    const pathArr = req.url.split("/");
    req.url = path.join.apply(null, pathArr);
    next();
});
```

Reassigning it to the url will allow any subsequent express matchers to continue processing it without having to take manual control of serving anything.

Comment: I'm much more inclined to change `req.url` than I am to redirect, so this looks good! But as I asked @strah - is it safe to use `path` as a url utility, considering it is intended for filepaths?

Comment: The path module is just a tool like any other. Given that you're using the url as a file path anyway, it's perfectly suited for it.

Comment: I don't want to sound nitpicky - I'll give ya the check in just a moment! But are there any other side-effects I should expect from `path.join`? For example I'm sure it will process the `./` symbol as well as the `../` symbol (which I didn't ask for, but which isn't a problem!) I just want to know if there are any other gotchas besides this case.

Comment: if your path is `/a/..`, you'll end up with a path of "." instead of "". That is, if your navigation returns to the top level, the placeholder is a ".". The path module is also system-dependent. It will function differently on windows vs. nix. If your server is windows, you can explicitly tell the path module to treat it as a nix by doing `path.posix.join.apply()`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding (begore first `app.get(...)`) this middleware:

```
var path = require('path');

// some other code

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var parsedPath = path.resolve(req.path);
  var root = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('Host');
  var redir = path.join(root, parsedPath);
  console.log(redir);
  if (parsedPath !== req.path) {
    res.redirect(parsedPath);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

This should be not needed as express + node should resolve paths as you would expect.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for!! Is it safe to use `path` as a url utility? I was under the impression it was particularly geared towards filepaths.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module instead, it has similar methods